# Xamarin Forms: native error with Microsoft.Azure.Mobile

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

Today I added to my project

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Analytics;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Crashes;
```

I should use Visual Studio Mobile Center but after that I receive an error for 52 times

> /Users/enricorossini/Projects/myInventories/myInventories/myInventories.iOS/MTOUCH:
>   Error MT5209: Native linking error: warning: object file
>   (/Users/enry/Projects/myInventories/my/my.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-ipad6.3-10.1.1/mtouch-cache/MobileCenterAnalytics.a(MSPageLog.o))
>   was built for newer iOS version (8.0) than being linked (7.0) (MT5209)
>   (my.iOS)

What can I do to resolve it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Our minimum SDK version is iOS 8.0 and above. In your Xamarin iOS project, open Info.plist file and set the "Deployment Target" to be at least 8.0 to fix the linking error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I discovered the problem.

In the **Application Output** I found that

> error MT1108: Could not find developer tools for this 10.2 (14C92)
>   device. Please ensure you are using a compatible Xcode version and
>   then connect this device to Xcode to install the development support
>   files.

I updated my iPad with the latest and I didn't update **Xcode**.